# glGetString returns null pointer on Nvidia but not AMD

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having a problem with glGetString on Nvidia cards. I have a proper context setup, and everything works fine on three separate PC's with AMD cards. I ran into the problem while using SOIL for image loading purposes. My application was segfaulting on a strstr call in SOIL on two Nvidia test systems, but not the AMD systems.

I found that glGetString was giving a null pointer to strstr on the Nvidia systems when SOIL was checking for extensions. I'm targeting GL3.3 cards with my application, so I modified the SOIL code to use the non deprecated glGetIntegerv and glGetStringi method of enumerating extensions. Now everything works fine.

My problem is solved, but I'm confused about why it was a problem in the first place. Is it just a difference in how Nvidia and AMD enforce deprecation?

Comment: Were you creating a core profile? Because if you were, neither one should have been able to use `GL_EXTENSIONS` with `glGetString`.

Comment: Yes it is core profile. The use of deprecated functions was unintended, but I wasn't aware that SOIL was using them until I had a problem with Nvidia. I guess it's just a case of AMD's driver having looser standards.